# Teamcity agent cannot connect to gitlab

Tags: git, kubernetes, gitlab, teamcity

I have one TC server pod and one TC build agent pod running in k8.
Another TC build agent is running in a separate server(connected with the TC server).

**Problem:**
Is with the build agent outside k8.

```
Failed to perform checkout on agent: '/usr/bin/git -c core.askpass=/root/temp/buildTmp/pass1564344 -c credential.helper= fetch --progress origin +refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master' command failed.
exit code: 128
stderr: fatal: unable to access 'http://ip/project.git/': Failed to connect to gitlab-ip port 80: Connection timed out
```

**What I tried:**

I tried connecting VCS in VCS root with TEST CONNECTION it's connecting.
My other agent inside k8 along with TC server is building fine.

Comment: `http://gitlabrepo/` looks rather suspicious. Is that some k8s service name?

Comment: no, that's my GitLab repo URL,(qn update)

Comment: problem is related to firewall misconfiguration, it's fixed now.